# VGA Cable or DisplayPort-HDMI Cable, which is better?

Tags: cable, vga, hdmi, display, displayport

I have a doubt: I bought a new monitor (Samsung S24D330), which has only VGA and HDMI inputs, my desktop (DELL Optiplex 9010) has only VGA and DISPLAYPORT outputs.

Now I'm using the VGA cable, using a DISPLAY-HDMI cable or an adapter, the quality image will be higher than the VGA? or does the conversion involve greater losses?

Comment: More than likely any adapter will be better than VGA, depends on the quality of the adapter, like this one supports 1900x1200>>>>>https://www.amazon.com/Fosmon-DisplayPort-Cable-monitor-projector/dp/B005644VGO

Comment: It also depends on whether the monitor has in-built speakers, as HDMI doesn't need an additional audio cable.

Comment: If the displayport is actually a displayport++, it can actually emit TMDS signal, which means it "natively" support HDMI/DVI with a "passive adapter".

Answer (score 3):

As your monitor is 1080p@60Hz, VGA, HDMI, and DisplayPort will support its maximum resolution, however, there are some differences between them.

## Option 1: VGA Cable

VGA (Video Graphics Array) is an analog standard, meaning that, although your resolution and refresh rate are supported, there could be quality loss due to factors like cable length, electrical interference, cable quality, etc...
Generally, VGA cables are inexpensive to buy, but they don't support audio

## Option 2: Dual-Mode DisplayPort (DP++) to HDMI passive adapter

If your Graphics card supports it, a DP++ port can output an HDMI signal when fed through an inexpensive passive adapter. This would mean no signal loss or latency, as it would be like a direct HDMI cable, and, like the latter, it would support audio.

## Option 3 DisplayPort to HDMI active adapter

As the DP and HDMI electrical signals are different, an active (i. e. a chip which processes electrical signals) adapter has to be used to convert between the two.
With it, there would be no quality loss either, as it would be converting uncompressed digital video.
This would be a more expensive adapter, and, depending on the adapter, it usually supports audio.

Personally, I would go with either options 2 or 3, in order to assure no signal or quality loss. In any case, the difference, for a regular person, between the three, should be minimal.